# Using NSNotificationCenter to call method in main app from extensions widget?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a widget that I would like to call back to my main app so as to make a call to the server to update data. I looked into delegation, but registering the widget's view controller as a delegate didn't seem very practical. So I moved on to trying to use NSNotificationCenter. I have set it up, but the selector is not being called. In my main iOS app I have this in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(loadNewData:)
                                                 name:kUpdateData
                                               object:nil];
```

And at the bottom of that file I have this:

```
/**
 * Updates the table when the today widget is called for updated info
 **/
- (void)loadNewData:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    [self loadTableData];
}
```

That's in my main app. Now, in my notification center widget/extension, I make this call:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:kUpdateData
 object:nil];
```

The postNotificationName being passed in, `kUpdateData', is a constant that is resolved to @"updateData".  I can see in the debugger that the postNotificationName method is being called, but the main app is not responding to it (regardless of it is in the foreground or the background). What am I doing wrong?

As a side note, the only reason I am doing this is to remove the need for repetitive code and re-implementing things I have already made.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know extension cant access or call main app methods... what can do is either do the server execution in extension or set a value  in shared NSUserDefault so when your app is brought to foreground you can check this value and connect with server accordinly.

Comment: I was afraid of that. That is ok then. I am already using NSUserDefaults, I was just trying to make it so I can guarantee my app has the most recent data. Guess I can set the background refresh time to something that isn't the default. Other than that I don't know/can't think of anyways to get the most recent data.

Comment: They operate to the main app with requesting and sending data!